# Error 1004 Vlookup VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have yet again another question to ask regarding VBA. I'm currently trying to use the VLookUp function. Here is all the information relevant  to the code:

```
Dim Template_Sheet As Worksheet
Dim Database_Sheet As Worksheet
Dim Source_Sheet As Worksheet
Dim FileUpdate As Worksheet

Set Template_Sheet = Sheets("Template")
Set Database_Sheet = Sheets("Database")
Set Source_Sheet = Sheets("Source")
Set FileUpdate = Sheets("NewFile")

Dim Database_Row_Count As Integer
Dim Database_Column_Count As Integer
Dim id_temp As String
Dim Row_Count As Integer
Dim Lat_Index As Integer

For i = 1 To FileUpdate.Rows.Count 'Count Rows
   If IsEmpty(FileUpdate.Cells(i, 1)) Then
        Row_Count = i - 1
        Exit For
    End If
Next i

Lat_Index = Source_Sheet.Cells(6, 1).Value
Database_Row_Count = Source_Sheet.Cells(6, 4).Value
Database_Column_Count = Source_Sheet.Cells(6, 5).Value

For i = 2 To (1 + Row_Count)
id_temp = Template_Sheet.Cells(i, 1).Value

Template_Sheet.Cells(i, 2).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(id_temp, Database_Sheet.Range(Database_Sheet.Cells(2, 1), Database_Sheet.Cells(Database_Row_Count, Database_Column_Count)), Lat_Index, False)

Next i
```

I get, you guessed it, Error 1004 on run. I've used almost all of these values for other applications within the sub, so I suspect my error must be coming from a miss-defined parameter when calling the VLookup function. Help is much appreciated.

Thanks! 
D.

Comment: Have you set value for Row_Count?

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry I forgot to add that in the code. Row_Count was defined earlier in the sub and returns a value that I have been using up until now.

Comment: In your code I see Dim Row_Count As Integer and then it's immediately used in a loop, without being set to anything. It means that your code reads as For i = 2 To (1 + 0)   - is that what you intended?

Comment: Also, what is the type of Database_Row_Count and Database_Column_Count? I don't see their definitions

Comment: Sorry the code is relatively long in this module so I tried to isolate only the relevant information to this problem. I've updated the file so as to take into account all the variables. Hope I did not leave any out!

Comment: Is it failing on the first run of the loop?

Comment: Yes. I've just hovered over all the variables used on the call line of VLookup and they are all defined.. The debug console indicates that the error is coming from the execution of the VLookUp call

Comment: Try to replace Database_Sheet.Range(Database_Sheet.Cells(2, 1), Database_Sheet.Cells(Database_Row_Count, Database_Column_Count) with a fixed range. Does your code work?

Comment: Side point, since you are not changing your lookup range within the loop, it might be better to declare a range object and set it before the loop. The code will be cleaner and you will be able to see what the range is referring to.

Comment: Yes so the error seems to be coming from the range definition... I'm not sure why though. All the cells return values... I'm currently defining a range before the loop. Will keep this post updated.